# Why is document.getElementByID returning null?

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage, angular-dom-sanitizer

**Goal**: Send variable from Angular application to iFrame on that page but living on another server

**Question**: Why is document.getElementById returning null? Am I using DomSanitizer incorrectly or postMessage incorrectly?

**(What I've tried)**

- I placed it inside ngAfterViewInit so It should be accessing it at
  the correct time
- DevConsole **error** shows: Error: unsafe value used in a resource
  URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

  - I read the article it mentioned (http://g.co/ng/security#xss) and
    applied DomSanitization   SafeScript returns a value, which makes me
    think I am using DomSanitizer correctly.
- I then read
  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Security_concerns)
  and made sure to do a check on event.origin

**Angular**(localhost:4200)

**chat.component.html**:

```
<div class="iframe-container"> 
    <iframe id="iframe_chatui" src="{{ chatURL }}/loading.html" class="chatiframe" allow="microphone; camera"></iframe>
</div>
```

**chat.component.ts**:

```
const isIFrame = (input: HTMLElement | null): input is HTMLIFrameElement =>
    input !== null && input.tagName === 'IFRAME';

ngAfterViewInit() {        
        this.safeScript = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(this.localeId);
        let frame = document.getElementById('iframe_chatui');
        if (isIFrame(frame) && frame.contentWindow) {
                frame.contentWindow.postMessage(this.localeId, 'http://localhost:4200');
            }
    }
```

**chatbox.aspx**(localhost:7078):

```
<html>
    <body onload="onLoad()" onresize="onResize()" style="overflow-x: hidden;">   
        <div id="ChatPanel" class="patient-chat" >
            <div id="LiveChatLog" class="ChatLogBox"></div>
            <div id="UserEntryBar" class="UserEntryBar">            
                <div id="divFileUpload"> 
                    <button id="btnAddImage" onclick="ShowImageSourceDialog()" title="Add Image"><i class="icon-camera"></i></button>               
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divEndVisit" style="display:none;" >
                <button id="btnEndVisit" class="EndVisitButton btn" onclick="ConfirmEndVisitRequest();" >End Visit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div> 
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function receiveMessage(event) 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            if (event.origin === "[ROOT_SITE_URL]" ||
                                event.origin === "[ROOT_CHAT_SITE_URL]" ||
                                event.origin === "http://localhost:4200") 
                            {
                            }                       
            var receiveChatMsg = function (message) 
            {
                if(randomCondition) {}
                else if(desiredCondition) { window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false); }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know it is returning null? Do you also get a null return if you select the container (i.e. `iframe-container`)? Also try changing the id so that it doesn't contain an underscore character: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Beginner_tutorials/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names. Or try grab it by its class instead of its ID>

Comment: @geoidesic Thanks. I am using DevTools in chrome looking at console and it shows null. When I try getting by class, I get error: "Argument of type HTMLCollectionOf<Element> is not assignable to parameter of type HTMLElement" *and* "Property contentWindow does not exist on type HTMLCollectionOf<Element>"

Comment: Can you select the iframe thought the F12 console?  is so you could try to defer it with window.setTimeout to also check when its inner content becomes available to use.  if (null) return window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);

 or else try document.querySelector('#iframe_chatui')

Comment: It's strange that even though the iFrame is in an ngIf=isLoaded , I tried not getting the variable until isLoaded was true, but its still null.

Comment: @Steve isn't setTimeout considered bad practice?

Comment: Did you try remove the underscore in the ID name?

Comment: When you get by class you will receive an array, so you should console.log that array and see whether the iframe is contained within.. of course your code which is not expecting an array will fail.. but if the iframe is within then you can easily pop the array.

Comment: @geoidesic yes, I was getting the same error for other ID's that did not have an underscore. I also tried it on the surrounding div with "iframecontainerId" no underscore and it still failed

Comment: I suggest you create a jsFiddle or similar to show the problem with more specificity.

Comment: @geoidesic the surrounding div by class has length 0 but the iframe has length 1. It's HTMLCollection. You are saying to pop that first item from the array to be able to grab it?

Comment: If I pop it, it's my understanding that it will no longer exist in the DOM, and thus I won't be able to postMessage to it

Comment: Well you don't have to literally pop it. You can just reference it by index. E.g. `my_array[0]`